# How to write a unit test for a function with specific type in kotlin

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, testing

Given I have function as follow:

```
fun myFunction(Id: String): returnType {
        val entity = repo.findById(Id)
        // this anotherProperty has a type: List<Type1>, where Type1 is a enum class
        val anotherProperty = entity.anotherProperty.toConvert(). 
        return anotherComponent.findByIdAndProperty(Id, anotherProperty)
}

fun List<Type1>.toConvert(): Type1 {
        return when {
            contains(Type1.enum1) -> {
                Type1.enum1
            }
            contains(Type1.enum2) -> {
                Type1.enum2
            }
            else -> {
                Type1.enum3
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to write three unit tests for this two functions(because I have three conditions for `toConvert` function). More like when `val anotherProperty` contains something, then I should call `anotherComponent.findByIdAndProperty(Id, anotherProperty)`.

But I just can't find where to call this `toConvert` in my test.

Comment: `toConvert` is an [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html), with a `List<Type1>` receiver. Can you update your question with an example test, with an example list?

Answer (score 0):

Basic tests for `toConvert()` function could look like this:

```
@Test fun toConvertReturnsEnum1() {
  val inputList: List<Type1> = listOf(Type1.enum1, Type1.enum2, Type1.enum3)
  val convertedValue: Type1 = inputList.toConvert()
  assertEquals(Type1.enum1, convertedValue)
}

@Test fun toConvertReturnsEnum2() {
  val inputList: List<Type1> = listOf(Type1.enum2, Type1.enum3)
  val convertedValue: Type1 = inputList.toConvert()
  assertEquals(Type1.enum2, convertedValue)
}
```

etc.

and then tests for `myFunction` should ignore existence of `toConvert` function - they should be like a blackbox so you know what is the input to the function (`Id`) and you just check result of `myFunction("testedId")` if it is one you expect.
In other words: create tests for `myFunction` in such a way where you ignore existence of `toConvert` function, you can imagine that you copied all code from `toConvert` directly into `myFunction` so you need to test whole logic in this function by providing input and checking its output.

You can also consider if you really need `toConvert` function to be added to `List<Type1>` - if you need it only for `myFunction`, then it would be better idea to create private method in the class/object where you have `myFunction` so it couldn't be accessed outside it. Then it may be also more clear you shouldn't have any tests for `toConvert` function and you should just provide all necessary inputs to `myFunction` so it would invoke all possible cases of `toConvert` under the hood.